# An explicit functional in $(l^\infty)^*$ not induced by an element of $l^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nonnegative linear functionals over $l^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55651/nonnegative-linear-functionals-over-l-infty)

**Setup:** Let $l^\infty$ be the set of bounded sequences (with terms in $\mathbb{R}$), and let $l^1$ be the set of sequences of terms of absolutely convergent series. Any element $y=(\eta_i)$ of $l^1$ becomes a bounded linear functional $f_y:l^\infty\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by defining $f_y(x)=\sum \eta_i\xi_i$ for $x=(\xi_i)\in l^\infty$. However, it is well-known that not every bounded linear functional on $l^\infty$ can be realized this way. ("$l^1$ is not the dual of $l^\infty$.")

Proving this was an exercise in a class I am taking recently. Classmates and I obtained the result via the Hahn-Banach theorem. Other classmates argued that $l^1$ is separable and $l^\infty$ is not, so $l^1$ cannot be homeomorphic, let alone isometrically isomorphic, to $l^\infty$'s dual. However, all of us were unsatisfied because what we *really* wanted was an explicitly computable bounded functional on $l^\infty$ not induced as above by an element of $l^1$. I and another classmate attempted to generalize the [Cesaro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) but he convinced me this cannot be made to work on all bounded sequences. None of us came up with an actual example. So:

**Question 1:** Are there explicitly computable elements of $(l^\infty)^*$ not induced as above by elements of $l^1$?  If so, what is an example?

**Question 2:** If the answer to question 1 is "no," is this because the claim "$l^1$ is not the dual of $l^\infty$" hangs on some nonconstructive axiom (e.g. the axiom of choice)?

Comment: In [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55651/nonnegative-linear-functionals-over-l-infty) I argue that the answer to question 1 is no and give references for the precise assumptions needed. It is consistent with ZF that $(l^\infty)^\ast = l^1$. The standard proof of the fact that $X^\ast$ separable implies $X$ separable needs some choice, so the argument involving this statement doesn't hold water.

Comment: @t.b. - Thanks! That seems to fully answer the question! (Moderators: perhaps the question should be closed as an exact duplicate?)

Comment: You're welcome. Following your proposal I'll vote to close as a duplicate. (By the way: I appreciate the way you ask your questions here very much. If only more questions of this quality were asked here!)

Comment: Jonas Meyer just posted two relevant links as a comment in the duplicate thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22661/explicit-element-of-ell-infty-ell1-closed and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem

Comment: @t.b.-thanks, this has been incredibly helpful; and thanks for the positive feedback.