# Existence of a $ l_ {\infty} ^*$ element

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nonnegative linear functionals over $l^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55651/nonnegative-linear-functionals-over-l-infty)
>   [An explicit functional in $(l^\infty)^*$ not induced by an element of $l^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91159/an-explicit-functional-in-l-infty-not-induced-by-an-element-of-l1)

Exercise: Prove there exist a bounded linear functional 
$L :l_{ \infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
such that for every 
$(x_n)=x \in l _ { \infty }$ 
$$\lim \mathrm{Inf} (x_n) \leq L(x) \leq \lim \mathrm{Sup} (x_n). $$
My current progress is that should be $L \in l _{ \infty}^*\setminus l_1$.
Also I know since $l_1$ is not bidual so there are such functionals.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Norbert I may missing something obvious, but why such functional implies the above inequalities?

Comment: here is a proof http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~furman/math569/Banach-LIM.pdf

Comment: thanks that's seems intersting!

Comment: Not at all ;)${}$