# How to prove that an existence statement cannot be constructive

Tags: functional-analysis, constructive-mathematics

Given the well known spaces of sequences:
 $$
l_\infty =\{(x_n), n\in \mathbb{N}, x_n \in \mathbb{R} : \sup_n |x_n|<\infty\}
$$
$$
l_1= \{(x_n), n\in \mathbb{N}, x_n \in \mathbb{R} : \sum_n |x_n|<\infty\}
$$
we can prove, by Hahn-Banach theorem, that $l_1\subsetneqq( l_\infty)^*$, where $( l_\infty)^*$ is the dual space of $ l_\infty$. But it seems that it's impossible to show explicitly an element of $( l_\infty)^*/l_1$.

[Here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/papers/difficult.pdf) I found that "*it is impossible for an explicit example to be constructed*", but there is not a proof of this statement. 
I found the same statement also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem$), but again without proof.
I tried to find a proof but it's too hard for me. Someone can give me a sketch of the proof, or indicate an accessible source where I can find such proof?
I'm interested to this question because it's connected with that [Do we really need reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078593/do-we-really-need-reals), being an example of a non constructive existence theorem with an explicit proof of the fact that a constructive approach is impossible. Some one know other similar results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given in both your sources, in the second one more explicitly. Shelah showed that, assuming ZF is consistent, ZF cannot prove that $(\ell^\infty)^\ast \neq \ell^1$. In particular, some non-constructive methods are needed to separate $(\ell^\infty)^\ast$ from $\ell^1$. Shelah's result is even stronger: even ZF+DC cannot prove that $(\ell^\infty)^\ast \neq \ell^1$ (Dependent Choice is a weak form of AC).

Here ZF is Zermelo–Fraenkel, the usual constructive set of axioms used for set theory. The non-constructive Axiom of Choice is also usually assumed, and it implies in particular the Hahn–Banach theorem, which in turn shows that $(\ell^\infty)^\ast \neq \ell^1$. Without AC, however, the Hahn–Banach theorem cannot be proved, as Shelah's result shows. Shelah proved his result by constructing a model of ZF+DC in which $(\ell^\infty)^\ast = \ell^1$. The exact paper of Shelah is probably referenced in Schechter's book *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations*, but it might prove to be too technical for you (or me).

Comment: If I understand: because AC it's essential to prove $(l^\infty)^* \ne l^1$ and AC is not constructive then the elements that make $(l^\infty)^*$ a proper superset of $l^1$ cannot be defined in a constructive way. But isn't this reasoning a bit circular? Maybe i've to think about a lot more .... And waht about other exemples?

Comment: Another question (maybe stupid) is Hahn- Banach Th. equivalent to AC ?

Comment: Sorry! I have just now find that question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285940/how-to-construct-an-explicit-element-of-ell-infty-mathbb-n-setminus?rq=1, so mine is a duplicate.

Comment: The Mathoverflow question you link to has an answer stating that the Hahn–Banach theorem is weaker than AC, though no reference is given. Must be common knowledge.

Comment: If you want to prove that something cannot be done constructively, you have to put this statement in formal terms. Otherwise it cannot be proved. In this case, we identify "non-constructive" with "cannot be proved in ZF". If you have other definitions for "non-constructive", you should check whether they are implied by this one.