# Extension of the limit operator on $l^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $l^\infty = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\colon \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|<\infty\}$
and the subspace $C \subseteq l^\infty$ given by the convergent sequences. 
We consider the linear operator $L$ in $C$ given by $$C \ni x \mapsto L(x) =\lim_nx_n$$
Is easy to see that $L$ is continuous with supremum norm hence by Hahn Banach extension theorem there exists $L^* \in (l^\infty)^*$ which is an extension of $L$.

There exists a explicit form for such extension?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look also at Banach limits [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) and [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~furman/4students/Banach-LIM.pdf), which are a special class of bounded linear functionals on $\ell^{\infty}$ whose restriction to $c$ gives the limit operator. Banach limits are not unique, but there are certain non-convergent sequences whose values are uniquely pinned down under any Banach limit ([“almost convergent”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence)). In this sense, you can obtain at least a partial description for an extension.

Comment: There is not. Such an extension is guaranteed to exist only by the Axiom of Choice, which is very non constructive. Such a functional provides an element of $\ell_\infty^*$ which does not arise from $\ell_1$. In some models of set theory $\ell_\infty^*$ IS $\ell_1$. Alas.

Comment: This answer mentions some reasons why this cannot be done explicitly (more precisely in ZF): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55651/nonnegative-linear-functionals-over-l-infty/55664#55664 You can also find some useful other links there.

Answer (score 3):

There is not. The closest you can come to explicitness, so far as I know, is to let $p$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$ and extend $L$ to the $p$-limit: $p$-$\lim_nx_n=a$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ $\{n\in\Bbb N:|x_n-a|<\epsilon\}\in p$.