# continuous linear functional on $l^{\infty}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $l_{\infty}$ be the space of all bounded complex-valued sequences equipped with the supremum norm. Consider the natural standard  basis $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $l_{\infty}$.  For any bounded linear functional $L \in {l_{\infty} }^* $, it is not difficult to see that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) L(e_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} L(f(n) e_n) $$
converges for any $f \in l_{\infty} $.

However, it seem that the above series does not necessarily converge to 
$$L(f)$$
since $\{ \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k)e_k \}_n$ does not necessarily converges to $f$ in the supremum norm topology.

I wonder if there is any explicit example such that 
$$L(f) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) L(e_n) $$
does not hold.

It might be a standard example but I am afraid that I do not have yet concrete background in graduate-level real analysis or functional analysis so I cannot easily come up with such an example..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite explicit, but any (continuous linear) extension of the limit from $c\subset \ell^{\infty}$ to $\ell^{\infty}$ [such things exist by Hahn-Banach] is an example.

Comment: See also: [Dual of $l^\infty$ is not $l^1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868787/dual-of-l-infty-is-not-l1),
[Nonnegative linear functionals over $l^\infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55651/nonnegative-linear-functionals-over-l-infty)
(maybe also some other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/55651)).
And at MO: [Explicit element of $(\ell^{\infty})^*  - \ell^1$?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22661/explicit-element-of-ell-infty-ell1)